# ERROR TypeError: this.remember.forEach is not a function at AuthFormComponent.ngAfterContentInit

Tags: angular, foreach

I have a problem in this part of code.

```
  showMessage: boolean = false;

  @ContentChild(AuthRememberComponent) remember!: QueryList<AuthRememberComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.remember) {
      this.remember.forEach((item) => {
        item.checked.subscribe((checked: boolean) => this.showMessage = checked);
      });
    }
  }

.html

    <div  *ngIf="showMessage">
      <p> You will be logged in for 30 days </p>
    </div>
```

Any ide please who is problem please?

Comment: Is `this.remember` an array? Add an additional check `if (this.remember && Array.isArray(this.remember))`

Comment: **1.** Try to do in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook. **2.** Try `Array#from` to convert to JS array: `Array.from(this.remember).forEach(...)`. **3.** Subscriptions inside iterations would lead to multiple subscriptions. And here you're assigning `this.showMessage` every time an observable emits. You should be using RxJS `forkJoin` function with `Array#map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `@ContentChildren` instead? `@ContentChild` returns the first element whereas `@ContentChildren` returns the list :  [angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren](http://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren)